# Multiple SQL statement is single query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table like this

```
Product     Opportunity  
P1            O1  
P1            O2  
P2            O2
P1            O3
P2            O3
P3            O3
P4            O4
```

Here Every opportunity may have multiple Products.
I have Opportunity = O1, O1 have only single product P1. Now, P1 also exists in Both O2 and O3. In Opportunity O2 and O3, there also have P2 and P3 alongside with P1. Within this relation, P2 exists 2 times and P3 exists 1 time. Now My result should be

```
Product      Count
P2             2
P3             1
```

Another Example

---

[image]

Here I have Opportunities (O1, O2, ....) and there have multiple products in each Opportunity. My input is O6 and It has two products (P2, P4). Now Search all opportunities that have either P2 or P4. I Got O1, O3, and O4.
[image]

O1 have additional two products -P1, P3
O3 have additional four products -P3, P6, P7, P8
O4 have additional three products -P1, P3, P9

My Final result should be Count of this product
[image]

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Comment: Can the links continue?  If so, you should provide more appropriate sample data and explanation.

Comment: Added another example

Answer (score 1):

```
    select 
    product,
    count(*)as count
    from MyTable
    where Product 
        not in(
            select 
            Product
            from MyTable 
            where Opportunity   
                in( 
                    select 
                    Opportunity
                    from MyTable 
                    group by Opportunity
                    having count(*)<=1
                    )
            )
   /*another conditions*/   
   -- And Opportunity='O1'
    group by product
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks, where I should put the condition "Where Opportunity = 'O1' ?

Comment: Well, you can write your conditions before 'group by', But I didn't realize your goal!!
It's really important, why do want to write conditions
because might change your query

Comment: I want this result only for O1, not for all opportunities.